# Search a string from a file with known size and some index characters

Tags: c++, regex

I want to find strings from a file that matches certain conditions. I know the size of the string and some position character. So as my knowledge the best possible solution is to create regex and search the string in the file.

I have created the below regex that searches all characters possible:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9#&()\.\-/=?%@!\^\$\\ \.\*\+\?\(\)\[\]\{\}\|]
```

below the code I have written using the above regex:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream t("file.txt");
    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char(t)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    smatch m;
    string allchar = "[a-zA-Z0-9#&()\.\-/=?%@!\^\$\\ \.\*\+\?\(\)\[\]\{\}\|]";

    //String of size five, have S at 0th index and B at last index
    string search = "S"+ allchar + allchar + allchar +"B";

    regex r(search);
    regex_search(str, m, r);

    for (auto x : m)
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}
```

But using the above code I am not getting correct answers that I am supposed to get. I think I am making some mistake creating the all char string but not able to identify my mistake.

Comment: Your `allchar` should be ``"[-a-zA-Z0-9#&()./=?%@!^$\\\\ *+()[\\]{}|]"``, and then you do not need to repeat it several times, use `string search = "S"+ allchar +"{3}B";`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. what do I need to do if I want to add white space also in the allchar?

Comment: Replace the space with `\\s`